# Is the QGIS Development nightly repo nightly?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

I've recently installed QGIS 3 (2.99) on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial using the [`Nightly build for Debian and Ubuntu`](http://qgis.org/debian-nightly)  following http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html . The installation was successful, and I was able to use the Development version of QGIS3 for most of the functions so far.

However, I've noticed that my version does not seem to be up-to-date with the nightly source code??, despite the fact that I've updated my Ubuntu several times.

I noticed this because I encountered the `schema "g" does not exist` bug https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15910, that was reported fixed a couple of months ago. Check my QGIS code revision, it seems to be something [committed](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/313ec55) half a year ago

Is the `Nightly build for Debian and Ubuntu` really nightly w.r.t QGIS code revisions?

Also, is there a way to ensure that my repo is updated? I'm thinking about removing QGIS entirely, and then reinstall. But I'd better ask here first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the Debian repository is not up to date for Ubuntu 16.04. From its `Packages` file (http://qgis.org/debian-nightly/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages), it has packages circa Jan 2017 as of mid-June 2017

Package: libqgis-analysis2.99.0
Source: qgis
Version: 1:2.99.0+git20170110+313ec55+24xenial
...

The Ubuntugis repository on the other hand is more up to date (http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages)

Package: libqgis-analysis2.99.0
Source: qgis
Version: 1:2.99.0+git20170617+cb1f98f+24xenial-ubuntugis

, which seems to be hosting nightly packages.

I installed qgis3 on using Ubuntugis repo and it seems to be working OK so far.
The QGIS code revision https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/cb1f98f seems to be from yesterday.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Does the latest stable get substituted by the nightly following this method or is there a way to keep the stable and have both?

Answer (score 2):

See also http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#id15

The **debian xenial** repo is still compiled against GDAL 1.11.3, so I guess the devs would run into problems with the current nightly code. You have to use the **ubuntugis xenial** repo.

**Debian yakkety** and **zesty** repos are up to date using GDAL 2 and git 20170617.
Since ubuntugis does not support yakkety and zesty, there is no other build of QGIS nightly for those dists.